# Exporting AnyLogic dataset log files as outputs in Cloud model

Tags: anylogic

I want to upload my AnyLogic model to AnyLogic Cloud through the run configuration process, and for outputs, I want to add several dataset log files. I was wondering how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the datasets themselves as model outputs; graphs for them will then be included in the Cloud experiments' dashboards.

The AnyLogic Cloud doesn't currently support having Excel *outputs* from your models (just Excel inputs), so you can't use AnyLogic-database-dataset-logs exported to Excel. But you can now (since the most recent version) download the outputs from all your model runs in JSON format (which would include the dataset data).

Otherwise you have to do it 'Cloud-natively' instead; e.g., write relevant output data to some Cloud-based database (like an Amazon database). That obviously requires the Java knowledge on how to do that (and an AnyLogic Cloud subscription, or Private Cloud installation, to be able to access external resources).